# Redundant data or UNION

Tags: sql-server, database-design, t-sql, architecture

I couldn't come up with better title.

I'm preparing data structure for GDPR and I ran into one problem.
I have two types of legal basis for storing the personal data:

- Law
- User specific (consent)

So some of the purposes for collecting data apply to all users (law) and some of them apply only to users which gave consent.

I have relation table `Consent` between `User` and `DataCollectionPurpose`.

1. Should I fill it only with data where user actually gave consent.
2. Should I fill it with "fake" data because law applies to user whether they gave consent or not.

Solution 1 will make me write two separate queries and union them, solution 2 will fill table with loads of redundant data.

EDIT: Added code for testing

```
/*
CREATE TABLE [Rule]
(
      ID int
      , RuleName varchar(30)
      , IsGlobal bit
);


CREATE TABLE Person
(
      ID int
      , [Name] varchar(30)
);


CREATE TABLE PersonRule
(
      PersonID int
      , RuleID int
);

INSERT INTO dbo.Person (ID, [Name])
    VALUES
      (1, 'Tom')
     , (2, 'Richard')
     , (3, 'Harry')

INSERT INTO dbo.[Rule] (ID, RuleName, IsGlobal)
    VALUES 
      (1, 'LocalRule', 0)
    , (2, 'GlobalRule', 1);



INSERT INTO dbo.PersonRule (PersonID, RuleID)
    VALUES 
     (1, 1)
    , (2, 1)

    /*
    drop table PersonRule;
    drop table Person;
    drop table [Rule];
    */
*/

SELECT P.*, r.* FROM dbo.Person p
JOIN dbo.PersonRule pr ON P.ID = pr.PersonID
JOIN dbo.[Rule] r ON pr.RuleID = r.ID
UNION ALL
SELECT P.*, r.* FROM dbo.[Rule] r
OUTER APPLY dbo.Person p
WHERE r.IsGlobal = 1
```

Comment: If you create an [mcve](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2990/minimal-complete-and-verifiable-example) and add it to the question you may (a) figure out which one you prefer, or (b) get a great answer showing why one of the two is the best choice.

Comment: Depends in a lot of considerations, also you can have a user table in this case you can have a "Jonh Doe" user flagged as "represents everyone/anyone" or just let that field nullable. The last solution will demand left outter joins but both has good and bad sides, do you need a opnion based answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use solution 2, but you should have a stronger INSERT logic validation, to check whether data has already a policy or not.

So it would be something like:

- check for law rules first (applies to all your users) check for user
- consent rule (user specific, so you have to relate it to userID)

So you can use tables: `User`, `DataCollectionPurpose`(a flag for law or user consent) and `Consent`(so you will join to it where your flag in the other table is for user consent)

Hope this helps!